# Не работают часы

Tags: arduino

Почему не работают часы? Вместо определённых цифр летают какие-то символы и квадратики :

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> 
LiquidCrystal lcd(13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8); 
String message; 


void setup() { 
  lcd.begin(16, 2); 
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 
} 

void loop() { 
  int long ms = 0; 
  for (ms = 0; ms < 1000; ms++) { 
    lcd.setCursor(9, 0); 
    lcd.print(ms); 
    delay(1); 
    message = ""; 
  } 
  int long s = 0; 
  for (s = 0; s < 60; s++) { 
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0); 
    lcd.print(s); 
    lcd.print("."); 
    delay(1000); 
    message = ""; 
  } 

  int long m = 0; 
  unsigned long time_m = 60000; 
  for (m = 0; m < 60; m++) { 
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0); 
    lcd.print(m); 
    lcd.print("."); 
    delay(time_m); 
    message = ""; 
  } 

  int long h = 0; 
  unsigned long time_H = 36000000; 
  for (h = 0; h < 24; h++) { 
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0); 
    lcd.print(h); 
    lcd.print("."); 
    delay(time_H); 
    message = ""; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: К видео по вашей ссылке нет доступа, кстати (наверное, в приватном альбоме каком-нибудь лежит).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive обновил тему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых алгоритм часов должен выглядеть так:

```
for (char h = 0; h < 24; h++) {
    for (char m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
        for (char s = 0; s < 60; s++) {
            for (int ms = 0; ms < 1000; ms++) {
                lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
                lcd.print(h, DEC); 
                lcd.print(":");
                lcd.print(m, DEC); 
                lcd.print(":");
                lcd.print(s, DEC); 
                lcd.print(".");
                lcd.print(ms, DEC); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, при выводе, например часов, будут выводится числа 1,2,3,... в то время как хотелось бы видеть 01, 02, 03. То есть для часов вместо

```
lcd.print(h, DEC);
```

надо будет написать

```
if (h < 10)
   lcd.print('0');
lcd.print(h, DEC);
```

а для миллисекунд и вовсе

```
if (ms < 10)
   lcd.print('0');
if (ms < 100)
   lcd.print('0');
lcd.print(ms, DEC);
```

Наконец, чтобы часы шли точно, миллисекунды следует отсчитывать не в цикле, а используя функцию `millis()`. Например вот так:

```
void loop() 
{
   unsigned long time = millis();
   unsigned long hours = time / 3600000L;
   hours = hours % 24;
   time = time % 3600000L;
   unsigned long minutes = time / 60000;
   time = time % 60000;
   unsigned long seconds = time / 1000;
   unsigned long milliseconds = time % 1000;
   lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
   lcd.print(hours, DEC); 
   lcd.print(":");
   lcd.print(minutes, DEC); 
   lcd.print(":");
   lcd.print(seconds, DEC); 
   lcd.print(".");
   lcd.print(milliseconds, DEC);
}
```